# Does the input audio have to be on google storage?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-speech

I've been looking through the questions, and got me wondering,
do the audios have to be on the google storage? or are there any other ways to process them?

I am planning to record the audio on the phone and then process it through the speech-to-text API.
So I was wondering if I have to find a way to automatically upload it to gs first then process it.

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

You can either send bytes or upload to Google Storage: https://cloud.google.com/speech-to-text/docs/reference/rest/v1/RecognitionAudio

Answer (score 0):

Google Cloud Storage (GCS) is the best place for not mutable object (BLOB). It can be text, videos, audios, pictures, binaries, zip,... Just keep in mind that isn't a file system: you can just WRITE, READ and DELETE.

- No move: The move command copy the BLOB in the target destination and then delete the original
- No update: The full content is rewrite. You can activate the versioning to keep the different version of a same document. *Note: you can update the metadata of a BLOB, but not the content*

So, to answer to your question, GCS is the right place for your files, and Speech to text (like almost all the Google Cloud product) can read directly in GCS.

About your processing and the automation, can you describe more what you want? Synchronous or not? Which part must be automatic? Are the users authenticated and how?